# Delete a row from multidimensional array returned by SQL query

Tags: sql, powershell

I have the following select query that returns the following multi dimension array:

```
ID|Name |FruitOrder                           
1 |Sarah|Apple, Banana, Orange, Peach, Mangoes
2 |John |Apple, Banana                          
3 |Mary |Peach, Mangoes                       
4 |Mark |Mangoes
```

Powershell Code:

```
$SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCommand                  
$SQLDataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.fill($SQLDataset) | out-null 

$SQLConnection.close()
Return $SQLDataset.Tables
```

Question: How do I delete row 3 from the data set? I can of course filter my SQL query, but the real code will need to filter out thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index into the `Rows` collections of the table in question and use [`DataRow.Delete()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.delete):

```
$SQLDataset.Tables[0].Rows[2].Delete()
$SQLDataset.AcceptChanges()

return $SQLDataset.Tables[0]
```

Comment: works but leaves the rows as null. Any suggestion to actually delete them?

Comment: @LBNHTX Looks like you need to call `AcceptChanges` to commit the deletion, updated answer